# Unable to enter text as the field is disabled

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" type="number" access-control="create_rate" ng-disabled="vm.state.disabled" required="required" name="amount" ng-model="vm.rate.user_amount"/>
```

I have used:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", merchantRate.addNewRatesCashback);
merchantRate.addNewRatesCashback.sendKeys(rate);
```

But I got an error saying `removeAttribute` can't be identified.

Can anyone please help me to send text into the disabled field using java/javascript.

Comment: Why are you having to remove this?  If this is a functional test, it seems a little odd that you have to do this . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is looking for an attribute `disabled` (which your form field doesn't have) - it's looking for

```
<input type=text value="Some text" disabled />
```

What you need to do is remove the attribute `ng-disabled` which your form field does have.

That should be enough to allow you to enter text into the field.

Comment: Hi Kate thanks for you reply, i changed to ng-disabled but i got an error as " org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='form-body']/div[3]/div[1]/input[@name='amount']"}"  but i can see in the DoM/firefinder the xpath is correct and i can find the element

Comment: Hi Kate done the changes as suggested and it is working fine now, thank you so much  :)